# Google Cloud Platform Dataflow is not Loading or Down

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am facing a problem of dataflow not loading even after 30minutes of staying. How do I complete that Lab,
The Task is:- Make a chart on dataflow by running a query on BigQuery.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Dataflow isn't loading while accessing it from bigquery directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the second option.

We can also start dataflow in another tab and restarting it from the new phase will help it in loading correctly. Then using make a new chart using a big query option with a query that has completed the task.